# Debugger not hitting breakpoint in .NET code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2005, c#-2.0

I have a C# code which I am running using VS 2005.

I have put up several breakpoints in the code. When I run the code in debug mode, none of my breakpoints are reached.

However the code runs successfully.
I tried putting breakpoints at basic `Page_load`.

I have already tried clearing my Temporary ASP.NET files in Windows folder, cleaning the solution, getting all the files again from the code repository. But it is still the same.

Comment: post code and line numbers where you are trying to break. Initial thought is that the code that you think you should be breaking on isn't actually running.

Comment: This is a snippet for the code I am working on

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                theData = commonDAC.GetApplicationConfiguration();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {try{
                  theData = commonDAC.GetApplicationConfiguration();
                }
             catch (Exception ex1){
                throw ex1;
             }
     }
     try{
                if (Page.IsPostBack)
                { 
                    setUserRoleFlags(); 
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it has something to do with VS2005 and IE8. Both of them doesn't work well while debugging. I got this information from following link - 
[VS 2005 - IE8 issue](http://weblogs.asp.net/abdullaabdelhaq/archive/2009/06/01/VS-Debug-Problem-with-IE8.aspx)

Eventually, I made some changes and now can debug through the code. Following are the steps I took -

- Go to Debug --> Attach to Process...
- Select aspnet_wp.exe process and click Attach.
- Go to Control Panel --> Administrative Tools --> IIS
- Go to your website/application start page.
- Right click and hit browse.

After which the execution stops at all the breakpoint.

I know this is laborious procedure, but at least it is working after me having to deal with putting up alert boxes.